# Maps: how to remove provinces boundaries

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to use the R package "maps".
If I do somethng like:

```
library(maps)
map('italy', fill = TRUE, col="white", boundary = FALSE)
```

I obtain:
[image]

I want to remove the boundaries of the provinces, so I try to do:

```
library(maps)
map('italy', fill = FALSE, col="white", boundary = FALSE)
```

I get the error:

> Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary,
>   interior, : all data out of bounds

Do you know how can I remove the boundatries of **provinces** (keeping only the boundaries of the **regions**)?

Comment: fill = FALSE excludes the other two options. For other countries the provinces are turned off by default. Help file doesn't really help...

Comment: no way of doing what you are asking with the dataset provided by `library(maps)`  because it only comes with information at province level (EU NUTS III). You should manually assign to which region each province belongs and then dissolve the polygons based on that field. But the easiest solution is using a dataset that comes already with that info (see here: [link](http://www.gadm.org/country)

Comment: Thanks very much #G.Cocca. It's exactly what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's got to be a better way than this ... but it suffice for your needs.

```
library(maps)
map("italy", interior=FALSE, fill=TRUE, lwd=2)
map("italy", interior=FALSE, fill=TRUE, lty=0, col="white", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even if the answer is the one given by @G.Cocca. Anyway, yours is useful too!